# Netbeans cordova project build fails

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans

I installed git and cordova (using node.js) correctly. But in netbeans, while creating the Cordova project it says:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\SHYAM\\Desktop\\HTML5Applicationeee\\nbproject
-Dandroid.target.device.arg=run -Denv.DISPLAY=:0.0 "-Dupdate.task.jar=D:\\NetBeans
8.0\\webcommon\\ant\\extra\\org-netbeans-modules-cordova-projectupdate.jar" "-Dandroid.sdk.home=D:\\Softwares\\Android bunndle_64\\sdk"
-Dandroid.build.target=android-19 -Dstart.file=index.html -Dandroid.project.activity=HTML5Applicationeee -Dconfig=android_1 "-Dios.certificate.name=iPhone Developer" -Dsite.root=www_nb_temp "-Dcordova.version=3.4.1-0.1.0

" sim-android check-android-template: check-cordova-version: check-cordova-project: upgrade-to-cordova-project:

cordova.cmd -d create C:\Users\SHYAM\AppData\Local\Temp\/nb_temp_project com.coolappz.HTML5Applicationeee HTML5Applicationeee

'"cordova.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\SHYAM\Desktop\HTML5Applicationeee\nbproject\build.xml:84: exec returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**cordova create commands run fine manually in the cli. I use Windows. Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Feels like netbeans' environment isn't being set correctly. That is, if "cordova.cmd ..." works from a command prompt, but not from NetBeans, I suspect the path variable isn't being set properly. I'm not familiar enough with NetBeans to know, but is there a place where you can point it to your Cordova installation (or set environment variables for script execution)?

Comment: Netbeans automatically gets it I think. However it works fine now. May be because I updated netbeans. thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if my case applies to everybody, but it should be noted that when working in Windows and setting the correct PATH for each needed command, as with cordova in this case, if the PATH is set under "system variables" instead of "user variables", then Netbeans (independently on its version, mine was 8.0) won't recognize it until you restart your pc.

It does not seem an issue with Netbeans itself, but with how Windows handles the PATH update (I have no actual knowledge on how it works, though, just empirical observation).